# Find phase components of complex number

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I am plotting the behavior of reflectivity in laser structure.

Belows is my code:

```
for mm=1:10000
deltabetaL=10-(2*(mm-1)/1000);
kappaL=1;
L=10^-3;
alphalossL=0.1;
phi=0;
c=299792458;
neq=3.5;
v=c/neq;
gammaL=sqrt((kappaL^2)-(deltabetaL^2));
req=(-j*kappaL*exp(j*phi)*tanh(gammaL))/(gammaL+((alphalossL/2)+j*deltabetaL)*tanh(gammaL));
A=abs(req);
theta=-angle(req);
Qine(mm)=deltabetaL;
Qreq0(mm)=A^2;
Qtheta(mm)=theta;
end
plot(Qine,Qreq0);
figure(2)
plot(Qine,Qtheta);
```

I expected to have figures for the amplitude `A^2` and the phase component `theta` of reflectivity as follows

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx6bUTVOinyySW9BZ1dXblFtQWc

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx6bUTVOinyyTTBJTHh6YjctZ0U

(Sorry. I cannot embed the image directly.)

The form of amplitude is similar to what I expected. However, about the phase, there is a big difference. So I thought the problem came from what I calculated phase component of complex number `req`.

Could anyone tell me how I can fix it?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your calculations. The author of the plot that you are trying to replicate set phase angle to be between [-0.5*pi, 1.5*pi]. Therefore, you need to adjust your theta accordingly.
Adding the following simple if-else statement into your loop seems working:

```
if theta < -0.5*pi
theta = theta + 2*pi;
end
plot(Qine,Qtheta)
```

[image]

Of course, you can come up with more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Can I ask one more question?
How do I can change the value of y-axis to be similar with the figure from the author?

Comment: @HiepXuanDinh you mean, you want to display it in terms of pi? Try `set(gca, 'YTick', (0.5:0.5:1.5)*pi, 'YTickLabel', {'-\pi/2','0','\pi/2','\pi','3\pi/2'})`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.